# Remove quotes from string

Tags: matlab

I have a MATLAB GUI that shows all variable names in the base workspace in a popupmenu.  The user can then choose a variable.  This variable is then passed into a function.  My problem is that I cannot find a way to grab the variable's value from the popupmenu.  I am getting a cell, which I convert into a string.

```
data = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
data = data{1};
```

The problem is that if the variable is named n, then this will return 'n', with quotes, when I need it to return it without quotes.  So, when I try to get the value, it does not work.

```
data = evalin('base','data');
```

How do I remove the quotes from the string?

Comment: What is the value of data? ''n'' or just 'n'?

Comment: The value of the data could be anything; it's user defined.  I'm looking for the name of the variable without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the most efficient way, especially if you have a lot of variables in the popup menu, but could you store your variables in the handles structure of the GUI, and when the user selects a variable name from the popup menu it triggers a switch/case scenario in which you use strcmp, for example, to evaluate what the variable is and thus get its value form the handles structure?

Or maybe create some kind of lookup table in the UserData property of the popup menu, so that each 'String' displayed in the popup menu can be related to the corresponding variable, after which you get its value and can then pass to other callbacks?

I can't test it with a simple script right now and that's only ideas; I'll check tomorrow unless someone comes up with an idea in the meantime!

Comment: Unfortunately no, the variables must reside in the base workspace, therefore their names are unknown at runtime.

Comment: oh shoot sorry then.That's a very interesting problem I'll check into it!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can try this:

```
data = get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value');
```

Use `'Value'` instead of `'String'`.

Comment: I actually tried this before posting this question, and it doesn't work.  This is because it won't map the value property to the string (variable name) that it represents.  Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Place a break-point after the call-function related to `popupmenu1`. Then, evaluate `data = get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value');` If not worked send me your `M-file` and GUI figure.

Comment: When I stop it there, it returns a cell.  If I convert it to a string, I get ''n'', not 'n'.

Comment: What is the content of your `popupmenu1`?

Comment: Could you try to find class of your cell contents. i.e `class(data)` and `class(data{1})`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59730/discussion-between-nematollah-zarmehi-and-servers).